# SQL - Results that have more than X instances in a time period

Tags: sql, t-sql, date

I am working with some laboratory data that relates to blood transfusions and need to pull some statistics of certain transfusion events that occur within a time frame.

I need to find which patients had 3 or more blood transfusions within a 4 hour period.

The data I am working with has each transfusion with a row id, patient id, transfusion date time and a transfused product.

Eg:

```
row_id, patient_id, transfusion_datetime, blood_group, product
1085441, AB112, 2014-03-29 16:27:00.000, B POS, Red Cells
1087441, AB112, 2014-03-30 21:11:00.000, B POS, Red Cells
1087443, AB112, 2014-03-30 21:11:00.000, B POS, Red Cells
1088208, AB112, 2014-03-30 22:32:00.000, B POS, Red Cells
1088408, AB112, 2014-03-30 22:48:00.000, B POS, Red Cells
1088693, AB333, 2014-03-30 19:25:00.000, O POS, Red Cells
1089426, AB333, 2014-03-30 18:07:00.000, O POS, Red Cells
1088529, BB777, 2014-03-30 11:12:00.000, B NEG, Red Cells
1083933, AB333, 2014-03-30 09:31:00.000, O POS, Red Cells
1083932, AB333, 2014-03-30 07:18:00.000, O POS, Red Cells
```

As you can see from above Patient AB112 fits my selection criteria as they had 4 units transfused within 4 hours of each other (rows 1087441, 1087443, 1088208, 1088408). Once I have those 4 row ids then I can bring back that patient and transfusion information.

I have a problem where the patient ID stays with the patient throughout their lives so they may have every transfusion ever received at a hospital (some patients require a lot of transfusions quite frequently).

I initially am limiting my search by the transfusion_datetime between a certain value.

From there I want to look at all the unique patient IDs and then list out each transfusion and then enumerate through each of them to see whether 3 or more exist within a 4 hour period and store those row IDs to use and bring additional information back for.

However my problem exists because I am unsure how to use a rolling time span window (of 4 hours) to iterate through each record for a patient.

Please help. Thank you.

Edit: Using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: You say tsql, which narrows it significantly, but what RDBMS and which version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, SQL Server 2008 R2. I'll update question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Just saw your response that you are in 2008R2. You can do the same basic thing, but need to to a self join using ROW_NUMBER() since LAG() is not available. I'll see if I can show that, too.

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Transfusion (
  row_id INT
, patient_id VARCHAR(5)
, transfusion_datetime DATETIME
, blood_group VARCHAR(5)
, product VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO Transfusion VALUES 
(1085441,'AB112','2014-03-29 16:27:00.000','B POS','Red Cells')
,(1087441,'AB112','2014-03-30 21:11:00.000','B POS','Red Cells')
,(1087443,'AB112','2014-03-30 21:11:00.000','B POS','Red Cells')
,(1088208,'AB112','2014-03-30 22:32:00.000','B POS','Red Cells')
,(1088408,'AB112','2014-03-30 22:48:00.000','B POS','Red Cells')
,(1088693,'AB333','2014-03-30 19:25:00.000','O POS','Red Cells')
,(1089426,'AB333','2014-03-30 18:07:00.000','O POS','Red Cells')
,(1088529,'BB777','2014-03-30 11:12:00.000','B NEG','Red Cells')
,(1083933,'AB333','2014-03-30 09:31:00.000','O POS','Red Cells')
,(1083932,'AB333','2014-03-30 07:18:00.000','O POS','Red Cells')
```

If using SQL Server 2012+ you can accomplish this sort of rolling window query using LAG().

```
;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT patient_id
        ,transfusion_datetime
        ,LAG(transfusion_datetime,2,0) OVER (PARTITION BY patient_id ORDER BY transfusion_datetime) transfusion_datetime_2_prior 
        --if the order of row_id is reliable then order the lag by that instead of transfusion_datetime
    FROM Transfusion   
)
SELECT patient_id
  FROM cte
 WHERE DATEDIFF(HOUR,transfusion_datetime_2_prior,transfusion_datetime) <=4
 GROUP BY patient_id
```

If using 2005+ you can accomplish the same thing with a self join using ROW_NUMBER():

```
;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT patient_id
        ,transfusion_datetime
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY patient_id ORDER BY transfusion_datetime) rn
        --if the order of row_id is reliable then order the lag by that instead of transfusion_datetime
    FROM Transfusion   
)
SELECT a.patient_id
  FROM cte a
       INNER JOIN
       cte b ON a.patient_id = b.patient_id
            AND a.rn = b.rn + 2
 WHERE DATEDIFF(HOUR,b.transfusion_datetime,a.transfusion_datetime) <=4
 GROUP BY a.patient_id
```

In either case you might see performance gains by restrict your working set first to only patient that have had at least three transfusions, but I'm not sure that isn't work the query optimizer won't figure out on its own.

That would look like the following, but I'd test both against real data.

```
;WITH PatientHaving3OrMore AS (
  SELECT patient_id
    FROM Transfusion
   GROUP BY patient_id
  HAVING COUNT(patient_id) > 2
)
,cte AS (
  SELECT a.patient_id
        ,transfusion_datetime
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY patient_id ORDER BY transfusion_datetime) rn
        --if the order of row_id is reliable then order the lag by that instead of transfusion_datetime
    FROM Transfusion a
   WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM PatientHaving3OrMore b WHERE b.patient_id=a.patient_id)
)
SELECT a.patient_id
  FROM cte a
       INNER JOIN
       cte b ON a.patient_id = b.patient_id
            AND a.rn = b.rn + 2
 WHERE DATEDIFF(HOUR,b.transfusion_datetime,a.transfusion_datetime) <=4
 GROUP BY a.patient_id
```

Comment: You will get duplicate records if the patient have more then 3 transfusions within 4 hours. But maybe that is ok? Example: 5 transfusions within 4 hours would give 3 records for the same patient, for just that 4 hour period.

Comment: @Johan You should't get duplicates. That why I GROUP BY a.patient_id in the final select.

Comment: Hi Karl, thanks for this info. I was able to pull back the patient_ids I needed and work through those but I have a further question (asked below) on how to get just the row_ids for these (since they're unique I can't do a group or count() on them. Much appreciated.